# How do I create a complete record with inheritance type delegation?

Tags: odoo, many-to-one, delegation, odoo-12

*example/models/example.py*

```
class Example(models.Model)
    _name = 'example.model'

    product_tmpl_id = fields.Many2one('product.template','Product Template',delegate=True,ondelete='cascade',required=True)
```

*example/models/product_template.py*

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model)
    _inherit='product.template

    example_ids = fields.One2many('example.model','product_tmpl_id',string='Item')
```

*example/views/example.xml*

```
<form>
    <field name="product_tmpl_id" widget="many2one"/>
</form>
```

My understanding was that a product_template record would be automatically created with example, but this field is *required* and not letting me save a new record. When I perform an import of the **example** *data* adding these columns at the beginning for product_template ("exampleNN", "name", "type", "categ_id/id", "sale_ok", "purchase_ok",...) I get a matching product template with an id of "exampleNN_product_template" and identical name (though example does not have name so it must be using product template).

Comment: When you use delegation don't use Many2one instead use the fields of product template like they are the same model. You don't have to manually create related fields you have acces to all template fields like they are declared inside your new model

Answer (score 0):

product_tmpl_id does not like being on the form view as it is required, yet not created yet with delegation inheritance. I used tree view instead to see product_tmpl_id. I was curious about its value after doing an import.